# MySQL advance query cache

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big prepared statement. The statement alone (without the data) is about 1kb and I am executing it very often. I was thinking, how to say to the database to execute the statement without sending it every time via TCP?

For example instead of sending `INSERT INTO dt(name, space) VALUES(?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?),(?, ?), (?, ?)` Can I somehow say `execute query no 23`

Obviusly I must send the data evry time as they change.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of prepared statements that you send them once so that they're parsed once and then executed as many times as you need? `$sth = $dbh->prepare(...); while($gimme_more){ $bind_params = ...; $sth->execute($bind_params); ...}` etc.

Comment: @Andrejovich: I understand what you are saying. The database saves time on optimization etc. I want something even better: don't waste time sending the big query.

Comment: Ah. Then perhaps you should look into stored procedures. Alternatively, you could create a view. I don't know which is better, but now at least you have some terms to Google for. Good luck!